# How to tell if sub-activity is finished when you cannot override onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I develop a custom view `myView` as a library. I fire the video playback activity from my view component's method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
myView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

I need to know when the playback is finished. I cannot use `startActivityForResult` and override `onActivityResult` of the activity because I have access to my view only, not the context it is used in - `myView.getContext()`

So I created my own activity `PlayVideoActivity` as a wrapper. Fire it with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mAdView.getContext(), PlayVideoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PlayVideoActivity.EXTRAS_URI, uriPath);
mAdView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

The `PlayVideoActivity` activity itsefl:

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRAS_URI = "uri"; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String uriString = getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_URI);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

The `PlayVideoActivity.onActivityResult` is the "place" I know the video playback is done, but I have no access from here to `myView`. AFAIK I cannot pass an object reference to another activity.

Is there any way to invoke `myView`'s method from this point?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Bundles to pass data to sub-activities.

```
  Bundle b = new Bundle();

  b.putString(uri, "video/mp4");

  intent.putExtras(b); // where i is the intent
```

These Bundles transport information from one Activity to another.